# Updating value of a subfield in MongoDB with Java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

I've quite new to MongoDB and it's Java driver.
I need to update the value of a subfield, but I can't find any examples online.

The document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("45678942342"),
    "user" : "me",
    "aStruct" : {
        "subfield_1" : true,
        "subfield_2" : true
    }
}
```

How do I update the value of subfield **subfield_1** to **false**, for every document that has **user** = **me** ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
db.collection.update({user : "me"},{$set:{"aStruct.subfield_1" : false}}, false, true)
```

In Java you can do it as follows :

```
DBCollection coll = // Define your collection here

DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("user", "me");

DBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject();
updateObj.put("aStruct.subfield_1", false);

coll.updateMulti(query, new BasicDBObject("$set", updateObj));
```

For more information read the following document.

- [Update document in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update)